Preventing Alt+Enter from Changing Value in ng-select Dropdown in Angular
I'm using ng-select in an Angular project, and I'm running into an issue with the Alt+Enter key combination. When the dropdown is open and I press Alt+Enter, it automatically selects the first item in the list, but I want to prevent this behavior.
Additionally, I have a HostListener that listens for Alt+Enter and sends a request to my backend. I want this listener to trigger without the dropdown selecting the first item.
What I’ve Tried:
1- Keydown Event Listener: I added a keydown listener with event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() to stop the default behavior, but it didn't work.
2- Custom Directive: I created a directive to listen for Alt+Enter specifically, but ng-select still processes the event and changes the selection.
3- Renderer2: I also tried using Renderer2 to attach the event directly to the ng-select element, but the issue persists.
What I'm Looking For:
How can I stop ng-select from selecting the first value when Alt+Enter is pressed while keeping my HostListener functionality intact?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You can create a HostListener in your component to capture the keydown event, check if the Alt and Enter keys are pressed, and prevent the default action. However, we also need to ensure that ng-select does not respond to this key press.
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
})
export class YourComponent {
  
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Check if Alt + Enter is pressed
    if (event.altKey && event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior
      event.stopPropagation(); // Stop the event from bubbling up

      // Your logic to send a request to the backend
      this.sendRequestToBackend();
    }
  }

  sendRequestToBackend() {
    // Your logic to send the request
    console.log('Sending request to backend...');
  }
}

 


Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately, this solution doesn't fully resolve the issue in my case. While the HostListener successfully captures the Alt+Enter key press and sends the request to the backend, the problem is that ng-select still processes the event before it reaches my HostListener, and it selects the first item in the dropdown.

remember about difference for stopImmediatePropagation() - it cancells all actions for the same event, so probably can affect & cancel action for ng-select too;
while stopPropagation() allows other event handlers do their's job
